# Munit coverage - how to override coverage by mvn command?

Tags: maven, code-coverage, munit

Given - POM file which has munit requiredApplicationCoverage defined as 75.

WHEN - tried following command mvn test with-Dcoverage and help:effective-pom
Edit - have mention command as comment to this thread

THEN - when mvn test executes it does coverage based on 75 not 100 and also in effective-pom  , it's value is 75

Refernce documentation :
https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/2.3/munit-maven-plugin#munit-maven-plugin-configuration-reference

Comment: mvn test -Dcoverage="<coverage><runCoverage>true</runCoverage><failBuild>false</failBuild><requiredApplicationCoverage>100</requiredApplicationCoverage><requiredResourceCoverage>50</requiredResourceCoverage><requiredFlowCoverage>50</requiredFlowCoverage><formats><format>html</format></formats></coverage>"

Comment: You should edit the question to add the snippet from the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the XML from the pom by defining it as a literal in a property. You have to edit the pom itself and edit the structure n the file, with values you want.